# CosmosDB Sql Query does not return same output in CosmosDB Emulator and Azure Portal Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to execute an order by query in CosmosDB. but I'm getting a different result in CosmosDB Emulator and Azure Portal CosmosDB data explorer. in CosmosDB Emulator the query works fine and showing the Result as I want. but while executing the same query on Azure Portal CosmosDB data explorer it doesn't show any result. I have checked the indexing policy for both the collection and it looks the same.

This 2 images show the emulator setting and query.

[image]
[image]

This 2 images show the azure portal setting and query.

[image]
[image]

i have no idea why this is happening or i have done something wrong with configuration. How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you confirm that a query without `order by` works ok? And without a `where` clause, just to make sure *something* is being returned? And that you have representative data already in your Cosmos DB collection? Also: you're using a partitioned collection - have you tried specifying the partition key? Could it be that you're only seeing results from one partition? Have you tried executing this query via code?

Comment: @Ajit Are u sure your cosmos db and emulator has the same data? Can you run simple query `select * from root` to confirm this ?

Comment: @Ajit Have test below suggestions to check the issue?

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk cosmos DB and emulator has different data because one is of the azure portal and other is local testing data in emulator but both have data with the same structure of documents and which satisfies the query conditions also

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes, without order by works fine returns documents and with where clause it aslo returnes documents.I have tried this query using code it gives only one document but there are hundreds of documents which staisfies the query condition.